# How do I center an iframe in bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

```html
<div class="ratio ratio-4x3 justify-content-center align-items-center mx-auto">


  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fprofile.php%3Fid%3D100085514265694&tabs=timeline&width=500&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId"
    scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>


</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap 5.  When I use "ratio" the iframe aligns to the right.  How can I use "ratio" and still align this ifram in the center?

Answer (score 3):

Probably going to be yelled at for suggesting this because HTML5 has deprecated it, but the `<center>` tag works well for this scenario.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<center>
  <iframe align="center" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fprofile.php%3Fid%3D100085514265694&tabs=timeline&width=500&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId"
    scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
</center>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `style="display: flex; justify-content: center;"` for the outer `div` element

```html
<div class="ratio ratio-4x3 justify-content-center align-items-center mx-auto" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">


  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fprofile.php%3Fid%3D100085514265694&tabs=timeline&width=500&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId"
    scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" ></iframe>


</div>
```

Comment: You should remove the Bootstrap class justify-content-center if you're going to state it as inline styling. Else it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your flex related classes to a div above, so that the div that is controlled by the ratio width & heights can be centered:

```html
<div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full">
<div class="ratio ratio-4x3 mx-auto">


  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fprofile.php%3Fid%3D100085514265694&tabs=timeline&width=500&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId"
    scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>


</div>
</div>
```

PS. I used Tailwind classes, just convert them to bootstrap 5 classes - I'm not sure what those are - probably just more verbatim: `justify-content-center align-items-center`